# How to get all methods from WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

How to get list of all methods from WCF silverlight enabled service from code.

I already have added service reference to Silverlight application.

Can I get all methods using Reflection?

If can please provide me example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the type of the service class you could use the [GetMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf.aspx) function to get a list of all the methods through reflection:

```
MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(TypeOfTheService).GetMethods();
foreach (var method in methods)
{
    string methodName = method.Name;
}
```

Comment: *Doesn't work* is not a very precise problem description that could allow me to help.